# $-\Delta u+\epsilon \sin u=f$ has a unique solution in the sense of distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

It's the last question in my exam.

> Prove that there is a neighborhood of $0$, denoted by $[-\delta,\delta]$, $\forall \epsilon \in [-\delta,\delta]$ the following equation has a unique solution in the sense of distribution.
> $$-\Delta u+\epsilon \sin u=f$$

Energy inequality shows that the homogeneous equation for $u$ has a unique solution.
But I have no idea the how to prove the existence.

I'm poor at functional analysis, so if any theorem applied, please let me know.

Comment: Is there any associated boundary data? Are you able to construct a functional whose minimisation corresponds to your PDE?

Comment: Just assume it's good enough, actually it's compactly supported and  integrable. I'm not able to construct such a function. Does the functional matters?

Comment: Any conditions on f?

Comment: @JesseMadnick Yes, maybe next year he'll use the same problem. It's just midterm exam, a small percentage of total score.